# A button when clicking on it loads a javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, electron

By clicking the button I need it to execute a `.js` file.
I tried to do like this:

```
const otimizations = require("../assets/scripts/optimizations.js");
const { is } = require("electron-util");
const Store = require("electron-store");
const { shell } = require("electron");
const config = new Store();
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron").remote;

function openHelp() {
  shell.openExternal('https://nichpc.com.br/')
}

document.querySelector("#start").addEventListener("click", e => {

    document.querySelector("#start").classList.add("hidden");
    document.querySelector("#loading").classList.remove("hidden");

    if (is.development) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector("#loading").classList.add("hidden");
        document.getElementById('status').innerText = 'Pronto! Agora faça alguns procedimentos manuais.';
        document.querySelector("#more-steps").classList.remove("hidden");
      }, 5000)
    } else {
      otimizations
        .start()
        .then(() => {
          document.querySelector("#loading").classList.add("hidden");
          document.getElementById('status').innerText = 'Vamos fazer alguns procedimentos manuais.';
          document.querySelector("#more-steps").classList.remove("hidden");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          document.querySelector("#start").classList.remove("hidden");
          document.querySelector("#loading").classList.add("hidden");
          console.log(err);
        });

    }
  },
  false
);
```

but it is not working
I'm using it in the **electron frameworks**.
Apparently I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: This question is only about javascript, isnt it?

Comment: Make sure this script is referenced in your window's html. Also, make sure this event handler is not inside the electron starter/main js file (i.e. the file that initializes the app's BrowserWindow etc.), as that file is only meant to run in the back-end.

Comment: @AnisR.I've checked everything and it's not inside the main js file.

Comment: Is this the file you try to execute or is there a part that you are planning to execute? Because I don't see such thing. Which function is called with the button?

Are you trying to execute the file in that new URL?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set webPreferences.nodeIntegration to true in the main.js file where you create the BrowserWindow object. You need that because you're using nodejs require in your js file. Something like this:

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    } 
  })
```

Comment: I already set the webPreferences.node integration to true. Is it not something in the code?

Comment: That setting is needed because you have 'require' statements in your js file. You will also want to make sure your "#start" element is in the HTML before your script tag that loads your .js file. If those are both correct then check to see if your event handler is fired when you click the button by adding console.log statements